# php 8.1 explode causes error when result is assigned to list

Tags: php, explode

I'm using PHP 8.1 and I'm getting an error when splitting on something that is not in the string.
This was not a problem with PHP 7.4.

```
$str = "This string has no dash";
list($a, $b) = explode('-', $str, 2);
```

`Error : Undefined array key 1`

The manual does not mention this behavior. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

So what is going on?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/BqsbK This appears to throw issues on 7.4 as well. Can you explain your usecase, why would you want to explode something that is not a string?

Comment: Why would you expect this to be described in the `explode()` documentation? The issue is with assigning to a list -- the number of elements have to match.

Comment: @JacobMulquin Why do you think it's not a string?

Comment: You don't need `explode()` to see this error: `list ($a, $b) = ["foo"];` will produce the same error.

Comment: I think what changed between 7.4 and 8.0 is that this went from being a warning to an error. And I guess you weren't displaying warnings, so you didn't notice the problem.

Comment: `list($a, $b) = explode('-', $str, 2) + array(null,null);` if you want to be silly?

Comment: @Barmar Parse fail by me, I read "splitting something that is not a string"

Comment: The use case is that I capture a string with preg_match(). Sometimes this string has a dash and some times it does not. 
Prier to 8.1 I could du this without any errors/warnings:
´´´list($a, $b) = explode('-', $str, 2);´´´
In the case without a dash $b would just be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$str = "This string has no dash";
if (strpos($str, '-') !== false) {
  list($a, $b) = explode('-', $str, 2);
} else {
  $a = $str;
  $b = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `explode` will produce a single element so you can't destruct the result array in two variables.

The error here is pretty clear: `$b` is trying to take a value from `array[1]` where `array` is explode result. As no dashes are contained inside `$str`, `explode` produce a single element, as stated before.

As you may not know how many element will be produced by `explode`, I would suggest not to use array destructuring for this kind of operation unless you're really sure about result count.

Answer (score 0):

Dirtiest little workaround to make the list destructuring work in absence of the separator would be indiscriminately padding the array with a fallback value (e.g. the empty string if you are not interested in the difference between absence of '-' and trailing '-'):

```
 list($a, $b) = explode('-', $str, 2)[]='';
```